# Iterable list of individually-addressable variables

Tags: c#, list, loops, variables, iteration

I need to build a list (or array, or collection, or whatever) of variables that I could both iterate through in a loop, and also individually address when needed. Say these are my variables:

```
double length = 5;
double width = 10;
double height = 7;
double weight = 14;
```

Now, all of these variables have to go into a list (or something), let's call it myList. And then I should be able to address them like so:

```
myList.length = 1;
myList.width = 3
myList.weight = 60;
```

But also iterate like this, to set them all at once:

```
foreach (double item in myList)
{
   item = 15;
}
```

This is just a primitive example, but the items in the list might be more complicated types, like custom classes, so I would sometimes be addressing or iterating through them like `myList.item.value = 5;` and so on. But I think you get the gist.

How can I do this? I know the most obvious way is to use Dictionary, but it would store pseudo-names only (as string type in the Key), so I have to have a separate class/struct with variable names, like so:

```
struct variableNames
{
   string length = "length"
   string width= "width"
   //...etc
}
```

And then getting/setting values like so:

```
myDictionary[variableNames.width].value = 5;
```

This way, I would get variable name suggestions from my IDE, and compiler would catch mistypes, but this is a very awkward way of going about it.

I suspect this can also be done with reflection (making myList a class, variables would be it's global variables, and then iterate through all members of the class), but reflection is relatively slow, and performance is important here. Maybe it can also be done with pointers, but that seems unnecessarily complicated for such a simple thing.

So, what is the best way to go about this?

Comment: _"But also iterate like this, to set them all at once"_ - you can't replace the iterator variable in a `foreach` loop - it will result in _"Cannot assign to 'item' because it is a 'foreach iteration variable'"_. Second issue: `double` is a value type, so unless you're writing unsafe code (not recommended) you can't change it via an intermediate variable.

Comment: @John - yes, I know. My code above is sort of a pseudo-code to describe what I'm trying to do. I know it wouldn't work, I'm just conveying the idea of what I need to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Use OOP.

```
public class Square
{
  double length = 5;
  double width = 10;
  double height = 7;
  double weight = 14;

  public Square()
  {
    length = 0;
    width = 0;
    height = 0;
    weight = 0;
  }
}
```

Then you can Instance the object:

```
Square sq = new Square();
sq.length = 5;
sq.width = 5;
sq.height = 5;
sq.weight = 5;
```

And make a list:

```
List<Square> squares = new List<Square>;
squares.add(sq);
```

For looping:

```
foreach (Square item in squares)
{
  item.length = 3;
  item.width = 3;
  item.height = 3;
  item.weight = 3;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but unless I'm mistaken, you misunderstood what I want in the loop part. I want to set ALL the variables of ONE object (length, width, height, etc.) to the same value in the loop. I want to loop through these variables in one object, not the same variable in multiple objects.

Comment: In that case, you don't need to loop, just modify the needed property. see the edited answer.

Comment: what you wrote (setting each variable value separately) is exactly what I want to avoid. There will be just one object, but I want to loop through it's properties (length, width, etc.) automatically like if that object were an Array or List.

Comment: Understood. In that case I would call a function that set all those parameters to the default (or received) value. Is that useful?

Comment: Not exactly... I will need to access these variables in a lot of different ways. They are going to be much more complicated (custom classes). Which is why I am searching for a way to make them addressable individually, like typical variables, and yet iterable together as if they were members of a list.

Comment: Don`t know how to do that. Sorry. Good luck!